# Converting number to time in excel - variable number of digits

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

I have a report which is downloaded from a Warehouse Management System.

On this report there is a time column which unfortunately puts the time into a string of numbers that can be anywhere from 5-8 digits long.

I.e.

```
22434900 = 22:43:49:00 with 22 being the hour, 43 the minutes, 49 the seconds.
2480000 = 02:48:00:00 with 2 being the hour, 48 the minutes etc.
54300 = 00:05:43:00
```

The 00 on the end (milliseconds) doe not change in each number so is quite irrelevant.

Is there an easy way to format the text in these cells so it shows as a time as oppose to a number?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would 1:01:00 be represented? 1010000?

Comment: If you mean 1 minute past 1am it would be 10100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TIME` with some math functions:

```
=TIME(INT(A1/1000000),MOD(INT(A1/10000),100),MOD(A1/100,100))
```

`TIME` takes 3 parameters: hours, minutes and seconds.

To get the hours, I'm dividing by 1000000, then `INT` rounds it down to the closest integer.

To get the minutes, I'm first dividing by 10000, but there is still the hours in that result. So I use `MOD` (which gives the remainder when a number is divided by another number). In the first example, the division gives 2243, and the remainder when dividing this by 100 is 43, which is the number of minutes I'm looking for.

To get the seconds, I divide the number by 100 and similar to the minutes, I use `MOD` to remove the minutes and hours parts. I am not using `INT` here in case there are milliseconds, which will be kept using this formula.

Also note that I am using the formatting `hh:mm:ss.00`, because excel complains if I try using `hh:mm:ss:00`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm late, but here's an alternate solution:

```
=TIMEVALUE(TEXT(A1/100,"00\:00\:00.00"))
```

Again, as mentioned in Jerry's answer, you'll need to use cell formatting of `hh:mm:ss.00`

Answer (score 0):

For your Warehouse Management System query you may want to try something like this:

•   Taking the 6 digit numeric time and making this into a string that the time function can handle

•   Using the digits function to avoid issues with varying lengths of data (i.e. 64512  vs 1113012)

•   Use the function Time over this string to return the value (this way we can add hours or minutes as the example below)

Here is an example to experiment with this and :

```
select MyTimeField
, time(int(MyTimeField/10000) || ':' || 
substring(digits(MyTimeField),3,2) || ':' || 
substring(digits(MyTimeField),5,2)) 
from MyTable where MyCompany = 1 and MyInvoiceDate = Current_date
```